# Insert list of dictionaries into Postgres table where each dict has different keys

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a list of Python dictionaries that look something like below where each dictionary can have slightly different keys.

```
data = [
  {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 32},
  {'name': 'Sara', 'city': 'Dallas'},
  {'name': 'John', 'age': 45, 'city': 'Atlanta'}
]
```

I also have a Postgres table that contains all of the possible keys that are seen within this list of dictionaries (e.g.: `name`, `age`, `city`).

I am looking for an elegant solution to efficiently insert this data into my database.  While I could iterate over `data` line by line, and insert each line individually, that doesn't scale so well to my actual dataset including millions of records.

I attempted to use the `execute_values` function from `psycopg2`, as seen in the example below, but that expected all of the dictionaries to have the same keys.

**How can I edit my process below to insert multiple dictionaries at once, where each dictionary can contain different keys?**

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

# connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="db_name",
    user="psql_user",
    password="psql_password",
)
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()

# get the columns from first dictionary
columns = data[0].keys()

# write the SQL query to insert the records
query = """INSERT INTO schema.table 
            ({}) VALUES %s
            ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING""".format(
        ",".join(columns)
)

# extract the values from each dictionary into as list of lists
values = [[value for value in line.values()] for line in data]

# execute the SQL query with the associated values
execute_values(cur, query, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the complete list of columns (which you should, if you are filling in a table), you can transform your data to fill in the missing values:

```
data = [
  {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 32},
  {'name': 'Sara', 'city': 'Dallas'},
  {'name': 'John', 'age': 45, 'city': 'Atlanta'}
]

import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

# connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="db_name",
    user="psql_user",
    password="psql_password",
)
conn.autocommit = True
cur = conn.cursor()

columns = ['name','age','city','state','zip']
empty = {k:None for k in columns}

# get the columns from first dictionary

# write the SQL query to insert the records
query = """INSERT INTO schema.table 
            ({}) VALUES ({})
            ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING""".format(
        ",".join(columns),
        ','.join('%' for _ in columns)
)

# extract the values from each dictionary into as list of lists

values = []
for row in data:
    x = empty.copy()
    x.update( row )
    values.append( x )
print(query)
print(values)

# execute the SQL query with the associated values
#execute_values(cur, query, values)
```

Comment: If you are gong to do dynamic sql use the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module and prevent SQL injection.

Comment: This certainly DOES let the connector do the value substitution.  The column names are known in advance and hence are not an injection target.  For you to accuse this answer of being "not helpful" is disingenuous.

Comment: The OP was providing a self contained example so everything was neat and tidy. The prudent course is to provide an answer that covers the not neat and tidy or at least acknowledge that the provided answer can be a security issue when the inputs are not known or validated.

Comment: There is a delicate balance on SO between "let me tweak your code to get past your issue" and "here is a complete rewrite that does the same thing".  I tend to believe the former is usually more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the dictionaries with a pattern (a dict that contains `None` for all the columns):

```py
#...

data = [
  {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 32},
  {'name': 'Sara', 'city': 'Dallas'},
  {'name': 'John', 'age': 45, 'city': 'Atlanta'}
]

# pattern - all columns with None as value
nulls = {'name': None, 'age': None, "city": None}

# get the columns from the pattern
columns = nulls.keys()

# write the SQL query to insert the records
query = """INSERT INTO schema.table
            ({}) VALUES %s
            ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING""".format(
        ",".join(columns)
)

# extract the values from each dictionary into as list of lists
values = [[value for value in (nulls | line).values()] for line in data]

# execute the SQL query with the associated values
execute_values(cur, query, values)
```

Comment: If you are gong to do dynamic sql use the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module and prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - Depends where the data comes from. I am not in favor of the mindless application of otherwise sound principles in cases where they do not apply. However, this is a subject for discussion, the scope of which goes beyond a brief commentary.

Comment: Except there is nothing in your answer that indicates that this is situation specific  and that  string interpolation can be and is a SQL injection risk. Without that a new user will look at this and assume it is  ok for all situations.  More to the point `psycopg2/3` has the tool to make safe queries under all situations so you should use it, if for no other reason then to promote safety.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - It's rather obvious that the keys in the dictionaries come from the application author, so the only SQL injection that is possible would be autoinjection. Just because a library has good tools doesn't mean I have to use them when they are not needed.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - For years on StackOverflow I've stuck to the principle that I don't downvote answers alternative to my own. If you love to follow strict rules, please consider this one for the future.

Comment: I will reverse the vote as the security concerns have been detailed in the comments. I will continue to down vote any answer I feel is not complete regardless of whether I provide an answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module.

```
create table books (id serial, bookcode integer, bookname text);

import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

data = [{'bookcode': 1, 'bookname': 'test'}, {'bookcode': 2}]

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost  user=postgres")
cur = con.cursor()

for d in data:
    col_names = list(d.keys())
    print(col_names)
    insert_qry = sql.SQL("insert into books ({})  values({})").format(sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Identifier, col_names)), 
                         sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Placeholder, col_names)))
    cur.execute(insert_qry, d)
con.commit()

select * from books;
 id | bookcode | bookname 
----+----------+----------
  1 |        1 | test
  2 |        2 | NULL
```

This of course assumes the columns can take `NULL` values. If that is not the case then you need to create some appropriate values for the missing fields.